# Should the IRelationalOperator.Equals return true regardless of vertex orientation?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I don't recall every having an issue with this method, but I am now.  As I understand  [IRelationalOperator.Equals](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Equals_Method/002m00000343000000/), vertex orientation shouldn't affect equality and if I take a polyline and reverse orientation, IRelationalOperator.Equals should still return true.

However, I am not usually seeing this: IRelationalOperator.Equals usually returns false although occasionally it will return true after a `ReverseOrientation()` (very strange--I'm seeing this maybe 1 out of 20 calls).

Is my understanding of this method correct?  If so, is this a bug or is there something wrong with my implementation?

```
IPolyline polyline1; 
IPolyline polyline2; 

//...other code

polyline2.ReverseOrientation();
IRelationalOperator relop = polyline1 as IRelationalOperator;
Trace.WriteLine(relop.Equals(polyline2 as IGeometry));
```